# Adding ng-show in a ui-bootstrap tab breaks active tab setting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

ui bootstrap 1.2.1,
  I have a series a tabs in a angular-ui tabset, and the visibility of the second one is determined by the selection in the first one.
  I added this tab, and I'm trying to use ng-show to make this tab visible or not, but I noticed that adding ng-show, when I set the active tab property (both from the tab control or the tabset), the selected tabs is not shown anymore.
  Removing the ng-show the activation of the tab works as usual.
  Am I missing something?

Comment: try ng-if instead ng-show.

Comment: glad to know... You should understand reason too

Comment: after further testing looks like is working partially ... works setting the active index in the tab component, but not setting the active property tab of the single tabset